# Multisite Manager and Redactee - links in entries being rewritten by *something*

Tags: multi-site-manager, file-manager

This is an odd one as these sites have been running for a long time and this issue has never previously come up.

I have a group of sites running under Multisite Manager.

On one of the sites (Site A) I have a news channel. Entries in this channel are shown on different sites based on categories - let's call the site in question Site B.

It has just been noticed that a link to a file uploaded to Site A is mangled when that entry is shown on Site B.

The link is hardcoded into the entry content (via a Redactee field) with the full URL. It *should* be something like http://www.siteA.com/downloads/my_file.pdf and on Site A this is how it is shown.

But on Site B the link is turned into http://www.siteB.com/news/%7Bfiledir_7%7Dmy_file.pdf

Somehow the link is being rewritten and because the downloads directory doesn't exist on Site B I'm getting the unparsed file directory.

I can't find any setting in Redactee to control rewriting of links so what is doing this?

**Update:** Even if I just write the URL in the text EE seems to replace the portion that matches one of the upload directories with {filedir_7}

**Update:** these sites are running on 2.5.2 - updating isn't really practical at the moment unless there is no other way to fix this and an update definitely will solve it.

**RESOLVED (sort of)**
I had a brainwave which fixed my particular situation. I simply removed the www. from the href of the link. So it became http://siteA.com/downloads/my_file.pdf This stopped *whatever* from recognising a defined upload directory and replacing it with the filedir_x tag.

I still have no idea what was doing that.

Comment: Do you have any sort of replacement plugins surrounding the content? Like Low Replace, or Hacksaw, or CE String?

Comment: Nope, nothing at all like that. Although I'm going to triple check as it was all built some time ago. I've never used any of those plugins though.

Comment: Hm. I'm thinking. :)

Comment: Thanks. Even if I just write the URL in the text EE seems to replace the portion that matches one of the upload directories with {filedir_7}

Comment: Well, then, there's definitely *some* kind of text-replacement routine running, either from a plugin or maybe an extension. Or possibly the actual field, if you're using something like wygwam?

Comment: Did you try disabling all extensions yet as a sanity check... does it still do the same after that?

Comment: Haven't tried it with Extensions off yet. Worth a try though. Adrienne - it's a Redactee field but the only link/url options available have been turned off.

Comment: I came up with a workaround which 'fixes' my particular problem (updated the question) but still have no clue how to fix this properly.